# Extract text from items

Tags: luatex, itemize

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\foo{%
\begin{itemize}
\item[x] hello
\item[y] world
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to extract the item label and the item text for each `\item` line. The document will be processed with LuaTeX, so I could insert nodes in the item label and perhaps at the end of the line to analyze later on. My thought is that I can insert special markers such as

```
\item[(m1)x(m2)](m3) hello(m4)
\item[(m1)x(m2)](m3) world(m4)
```

where m1,...m4 are calls to `\directlua{}` to insert a special marker.

(How) Is it possible to augment the `\item` command to insert those `m_n` markers? The text within `\foo` is fixed and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\mi`  and `\mii` with the `\directlua` calls

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}
\let\Item\item
\renewcommand\item[1][]{\Item[\mi#1\mii]}
\def\mi{<m1>}
\def\mii{<m2>}

\begin{document}
    \foo{%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[x] hello
            \item[y] world
        \end{itemize}
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried exactly this, but it didn't work.... Thank you!